# Extending ValidationSummary Method (HtmlHelper, Boolean, String)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I would like to make some changes so this method doesn't display anything if there are no form level errors.

Does anyone know where I can find the source code for this method?

Comment: The existing ValidationSummary method will not display anything if there are no errors (model or property) so you should not need to change anything. Or have I misunderstood?

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to make some changes so this method doesn't display
>   anything if there are no form level errors.

If you use `Html.ValidationSummary(true)` the method will not show property errors, only global errors. If you use `Html.ValidationSummary(false)` all errors will be displayed. If there are no errors in ModelState no matter which overload you use it will not display any errors.

> Does anyone know where I can find the source code for this method?

You could download the [ASP.NET MVC 3 source code](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/58781). You should be looking for the [ValidationExtensions.cs](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/72551#288016) file.